# AngularJS, Use passport without redirect/refresh on server side

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js, google-oauth

I'm using NodeJS, AngularJS and passport and trying to do use google+ login using [passport-google-oauth2](https://github.com/mstade/passport-google-oauth2).

Like described in the examples I added 2 routes:

- /auth/google:
- /auth/google/callback

In addition I saw that in all the examples the call to those routes is done via a link: 
`<a href='/auth/google/>Login to Google</a>`

Which work in my app.

But, I wanted to do the call the in the Angular way to avoid the redirection - which mean:

```
$http.get('/auth/google/')
```

When I tried it I got the CORS violation error

> "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource"

(CORS rules were added to my NodeJS server).
Is there a way to do it using $http.get and not doing the redirect in the back-end?

Answer (score -1):

Set useXDomain to true for the $httpProvider

```
angular.module('ngdemo')
        .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }]);
```

for more info [here](http://draptik.github.io/blog/2013/08/19/angularjs-and-cors/)

Comment: `useXDomain ` is [not a thing](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2956) in angular [$httpprovider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider)